# Migrating from Debian texlive to vanilla

Tags: installing, texlive

I had been using the native Debian texlive on Mint Linux for a time, with Texmaker.

Now I installed the "vanilla" texlive, in order to have a better package control with `tlmgr`. However, I believe I have to do something on Texmaker, or perhaps somewhere else, in order to recognize the new installation, because it isn't finding the new packages I just installed.

For example, after successfully running `tlmgr install mathdesign`, Texmaker (running `pdflatex`) will output:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mathdesign.sty' not found.
```

Comment: How did you setup the `PATH`? I assume that if you run `kpsewhich mathdesign.sty` in a terminal then you get what you expected? Note setting the `PATH` in say `.bashrc` is not enough, that addition will not be seen by programmes stared via, say, a menu.

Comment: I added the texlive bin directory to the path in /etc/profile. If I run `kpsewhich mathdesign.sty`, it returns nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: You should try to set the path in `/etc/environment` (and obviously, restart you desktop environment (log out and in) after doing that). In fact, `/etc/profile` is specific to `bash`, it isn't read by other shells (eg `zsh`) nor by all desktop environments.

Comment: @erickrf: Have you run `mktexlsr` or `sudo mktexlsr` to recreate the ls-R databases after installing the `mathdesign` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stated that you added the path in `/etc/profile`. But did you add it to the FRONT or the BACK of the PATH element?

There is already a TeX system installed on your computer, so the `kpsewhich` you are using is the one shipped by Debian in `/usr/bin`, and not the one from Vanilla TeX Live.

Possible solutions:

- add the TeX Live directory to the front of the path
- install a texlive equivs packages and remove all the texlive-* packages with `dpkg`/`apt-get`/`aptitude` (see http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html at the end for that)

Comment: I added the TeX Live directory to `PATH` in `/etc/environment` and it worked. Thanks.